# Rails 4 Inventory Application: database design and use of nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I built this application and it works nicely and is quite simple: https://github.com/ornerymoose/DeviceCount . It allows you to create a new entry for a device where you specify a count (ie, inventory amount) of a device.

Now even though this works, I've been told that it needs to be on a 'per location' basis. Ie, you create an entry and you will have 10 textfields (if there are indeed 10 devices. This amount will never change nor will the devices change) for devices, and for each device text field, you will enter a count for that device. You will choose location for a dropdown menu. When that entry is created, you will have:

-1 location

-10 Devices listed, all with their own count.

I'm struggling wrapping my head around how to design these models. Should I have an `Entry` and `Device` model? A separate `Count` model?

Would a nested form be the best approach here?

Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is too broad, but essentially you want a new model that `belongs_to` a `Location` and `has_many` `Device`s

Comment: How is it too broad? I provided a sample application of what I have and where I need to get to. Thank you though, that should help :) I realize this isn't horribly difficult but I'm having a tough time visualize the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'd be best with an `Inventory` join model (with [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)):

```
#app/models/inventory.rb
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
   # id | device_id | location_id | qty | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :device
   belongs_to :location
end

#app/models/device.rb
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :inventories
   has_many :locations, through: :inventories
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventories
end

#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :inventories
   has_many :devices, through: :inventories
end
```

This will allow you to set the "quantity" of the `device` for each location (will have to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)):

```
#app/controllers/devices_controller.rb
class DevicesController < ApplicationController 
   def new
     @device = Device.new
     @locations = Location.all
   end

   def create
     @device = Device.new device_params
     @device.save
   end

   private

   def device_params
     params.require(:device).permit(inventories_attributes: [:qty])
   end
end

#app/views/devices/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @device do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :inventories, Location.all do |i| %>
     <%= i.number_field :qty %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to create a new `Device` and have it's `qty` available through its `Inventory`.

Comment: Hi Rich, thank you for the detailed answer. I see what you're getting at with the join model (and I guess it wasn't clear in my OP), but it won't be devices being created, it'll be Location (maybe a better word is `Entry`). Each entry will have: the location/name, 10 devices, with 10 counts. Then you could view each entry on the index page.